# Slide div back with back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using sliding divs with this code:

html:

```
   <div id="container">

<div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
<div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
<div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>


    </div>
```

css:

```
    body {
      padding: 0px;    
    }

    #container {
     position: absolute;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;  
    }

  .box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
  }

  #box1 {
   left: 50%;
```

js:

```
 $('.box').click(function() {

$(this).animate({
    left: '-50%'
}, 500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', '150%');
    $(this).appendTo('#container');
});

$(this).next().animate({
    left: '50%'
}, 500);
});​
```

There is the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/

I would like to be able to use the previous button of my browser to go back to the previous div.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

EDIT:

I tried by just adding anchors, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: one way to do it is append `#DivId` to your URL, so when you go to this URL the page will focus on this div.

Like this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977714/add-anchor-to-sliding-divs#question

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly I tried. Each time I slide, I add an #DivId. But when I press the back button, the div doesn't slide back.

Comment: this is what I meant : http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/4525/ you can add some modifications to move the div to the middle if it is not in the middle when the page renders after a pushing back button.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this hashchange plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

have a function that executes on hashchange that slides the appropriate box into view

when you use your browser back and forward buttons it will change the hash and your code will run.

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    var hash = location.hash;
    slideBox(hash.substr(1));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks like it could work in my case but I have no idea on how I can apply it to my code. I tried and I didn't found how to make it. Could you give me a hint on how I apply that to my situation?